# ndk pthread vs java thread on android when calling jni function

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to call a JNI C function:

When should I call it from a java thread (Runnable, AsyncTask, etc)?

When should i call a C function that uses pthread ?

Comment: I need to execute a background task so my question is which advatages/disadvantages has each method

Answer (score 0):

Using a Java background thread to call a native method (directly with `(new Thread( () -> { nativeMethod() } )).start()` or indirectly via **AsyncTask** or some **Executor**) may be easier in many scenarios, especially if your C code should return its results to Java, or to issue Java callbacks.